# Eddy Current Correction without reverse-phase encoding Data

Tags: neuroimaging

I'm a beginner to dMRI analysis and am attempting to prepress data from the [ABIDE-2 database](http://fcon_1000.projects.nitrc.org/indi/abide/abide_II.html) (San Diego State Uni's DTI scan data) using the FSL pipeline (TOPUP->EDDY->DTIFIT). The TOPUP step uses two SE-EPI images to generate a Fieldmap which is later used in the EDDY correction step, however the ABIDE database reports to have already Fieldmap-corrected the data and hasn't included the Fieldmap for each patient, making executing the EDDY processing via FSL impossible. Looking through the Fieldmap-corrected data I can't spot any obvious eddy-current distortions (global shears, misaligned axes between volumes, etc.) and the data looks very clean, but I'm hesitant to move forward in analysis without being sure that not applying eddy-current correction won't create issues down the line.

I'm not sure if I've just overlooked the fieldmaps provided in the dataset's scan parameters or elsewhere, if the Fieldmap correction also corrected for eddy-current distortions (which doesn't seem standard based on my research), or if other methods exist to correct for eddy currents beyond Fieldmap data. Would really appreciate a more experienced opinion!